# How do I convert raw SQL query into laravel querybuilder or eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Im having a hard time converting this raw MySQL query in phpmyadmin. I want to convert it to laravel's query builder or eloquent. I already configured the relationships in the model. Can someone convert my query to querybuilder and eloquent? I tried some converter but it doesnt work for me. Thanks

Raw Query

```
SELECT count( * ) FROM users u, sectionschedules s, notes n 
WHERE u.parent_id=26 
AND u.section_id=s.section_id 
AND s.id = n.schedule_id;
```

Query I tried

```
$notes = DB::table('notes')
                    ->join('users', 'users.section_id', '=', 'notes.section_id')
                    ->join('sections','sections.section_id', '=', 'sectionschedules.section_id')
                    ->join('sectionschedules', 'sectionschedules.id','=','notes.schedule_id')
                    ->where('user.parent_id', '=', 26)
                    ->count();
```

Error I got

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user.parent_id' in 'where clause
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `'users.parent_id'` as the table `user` isn't defined.

Comment: what do you mean sir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
  $notes = DB::table('sectionschedules')
           ->select('notes.*','sectionschedules.*','users.*')
           ->join('users','users.section_id', '=', 'sectionschedules.section_id')
           ->join('notes', 'sectionschedules.id','=','notes.schedule_id')
           ->where('users.parent_id', '=', 26)
           ->count();
```

Comment: I got `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'notes.section_id' in 'on clause'` error sir

Comment: If you are going to post an answer to something which is more likely a typo, then at least point out what the changes you have made are.

Comment: Still getting the same error sir `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'notes.section_id' in 'on clause'`

Comment: can you check whether table `notes` has a field with name `section_id` ?

Comment: it only has `schedule_id` sir

Comment: Then how you join the table with `notes` ?

Comment: based on `schedule_id` only sir.

Comment: which is seen on my raw sql query above

Comment: `->join('users', 'users.section_id', '=', 'notes.section_id')` .what is the meaning of this join then ?

Comment: I just tried converting my raw sql query sir to querybuilder. why i wrote that because maybe im confused in querybuilder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200636/discussion-between-ronald-bustillo-and-jithesh-jose).

Comment: New error sir `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.parent_id`

Comment: can you explain to me what did you do? haha

Comment: check whether `users` table has a field `parent_id` or not ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$notes = DB::table('notes')
                ->join('users', 'users.section_id', '=', 'notes.section_id')
                ->join('sections','sections.section_id', '=', 'sectionschedules.section_id')
                ->join('sectionschedules', 'sectionschedules.id','=','notes.schedule_id')
                ->where('users.parent_id', '=', 26)
                ->count();
```

Users.parent id as defined not user.parent_id